# Eclipse external tools, white space in path vars

Tags: windows, eclipse

I am setting up a external tool but when I use the argument variables like this one: ${resource_path} for resources that contain spaces in the path (e.g. C:\Program Files) it seems the arguments get passed in split on the spaces in the path.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put quotes around the variable: "${resource_path}"

Comment: I was trying single quotes, DOH!
Thanks much!